# matplotlib colorbar smoothness

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot some data using contourf using this function:

```
cmap = mpl.cm.jet
norm = mpl.colors.Normalize(vmin=min(zi), vmax=max(zi))
ax = plt.contourf(xi, yi, zi, N=20, norm=norm, cmap=cmap)
plt.colorbar(ax)
```

The colorbar I am getting is this one:

[image]

However, I would like to have the colorbar more gradient such as this:

[image]

Is it possible to have it?  I tried adding N=50 to the contourf function but it did not help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The number of levels in the colormap will be the same number of levels in the contour. Your problem is that you cannot pass `N` as keyword to `contourf`, it's being ignored. Try this:

```
ax = plt.contourf(xi, yi, zi, 50, norm=norm, cmap=cmap)
plt.colorbar(ax)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add levels parameter to contourf:

```
ax = plt.contourf(xi, yi, zi, N=20, norm=norm, 
        cmap=cmap,levels=np.linspace(zi.min(),zi.max(),1000))
```

Comment: Adding levels will mean that `N` is ignored. But in your example it's already being ignored, as it's specified as a keyword.